# Initializing multidimensional array C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, initialization

In C++, when I want to initialize an array of some length (of integers for instance) I can just write

```
int* tab;
tab = new int[size];
```

where size is given somewhere else. But how do I do that in the same manner, when it comes to a multidimensional array? I can't just add another dimension(s) in the second line, because compiler doesn't like that...

It's a simple question I guess. I need that, as I'm writing an assignment in object-oriented programming and 2D array is a private part of a class, which needs to be... constructed in the constructor (with 2 dimensions as parameters).

Comment: Please see this: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/65-multidimensional-arrays/

Comment: `-1` use `std::vector`.

Comment: I've heard about vector, but I wanted to know if there's a way similiar to what can be done with one dimensional array...

Comment: "I've heard about vector". So you've heard about C++, now it's time to really learn it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `std::vector` is the safe way:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat(size1, std::vector<int>(size2));
```

if really you want to use `new` yourself:

```
int** mat = new int*[size1];
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != size1; ++i) {
    mat[i] = new int[size2];
}
```

And don't forget to clean resources:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != size1; ++i) {
    delete [] mat[i];
}
delete[] mat;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford `std::vector` instead of arrays you can use as syntax:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > matrix(rows, std::vector<int>(columns));

for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<columns; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = i+j;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get height/width parameters before the initialization of the array you can try:

```
int height = 10;
int width = 10;

//...

int tab[heigth][width];
```

Comment: you can not have run-time values as dimensions of automatic array.

Comment: That requires non standard extension: VLA.